# What does the "to" mean in this phrase and when to use it after verb

Tags: prepositions

I've started learning English a few months ago. I still have some doubts regarding the use of "TO" after verbs. For example, in this sentence:

> If you’d like to visit me some time, you’re welcome **to**

What does the "to" mean? What role is it playing in the sentence and when to use it in the sentence?

I've got a message right now which says,

> I have about couple of mails to read through and respond **to**!

Is not it enough to just say "To read and respond"?

Comment: [You should probably consider waiting a bit longer before accepting an answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: I will have this into account. You're definitely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid repetition, part of the first sentence has been left out (aka [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))):

> If you’d like to visit me some time, you’re welcome to [visit me some time].

The second sentence has some grammatical mistakes and should be something like (assuming it's referring to email):

> I have a couple of emails to read through and respond to!

In this case, however, it's a different thing happening (specifically a [stranded preposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding), I think). That corrected sentence can be rewritten as (with a lot of verbosity in the hopes of being clear):

> I have to read through some emails and I have to respond to them.